# Rails: is it possible to add extra attribute to a has_and_belongs_to_many association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, has-and-belongs-to-many

What I mean is if I have two models, connected by a has_and_belongs_to_many association, can I store other data in the join table for each association? That is, the extra data would not be part of a single record in either table, but instead of the connection between them.

My actual models are as follows:

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :assemblies
  has_and_belongs_to_many :packages
  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, :user_id, :presence => true
end

class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :parts
  belongs_to :user
end
```

So the point is that each part is available in many packages, and each package has different parts. What I want to add is a quantity. That would not be quantity of each part, but of each package of each part.

I can't find how to do this in ActiveRecord. If I was not using rails/activerecord, I'd just add a quantity column to the join table which relates parts to packages. I could obviously make this change in a migration, but how would I access the value using ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Short answer no you cannot with a HABTM relationship. It is only intended for simple many to many relationships.

You will need to use a has_many :through relationship.  In this scenario you will create a join model (PartPackage) where you can define the extra attributes that you need.

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :part_packages
  has_many :packages, :through => :part_packages

  has_and_belongs_to_many :assemblies
  belongs_to :user

  validates :name, :user_id, :presence => true
end

class PartPackage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :part
  belongs_to :package
end

class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :part_packages
  has_many :parts, :through => :part_packages
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 16):

There is a key difference between [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) and [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association) the Rails guide explains the differences between the two options in greater detail, however if you want to add data that describes the relationship then use [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-through-association) and you can access the model that joins the two.

**This is what has_many :through looks like:**
[image: Credit to the Rails guide.]

Comment: What program did you use to make such a nice outline?

Comment: (my internal ref #485 ) How do you update the appointment_date at the same time the whole record is created and also how do you read the extra attribute later on? I can only do it via Appointment.find_by............. but I would like something less wacky like patient.appointments.first.appointment_date

Comment: You can update the appointment_date attribute like this: belongs_to :physician, :touch => :appointment_date.

Comment: @MicFin he takes it from ror guide

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this is possible.

1) Add a quantity key to the packages_parts join table

2)  Add this to your Part model

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :packages, -> { select("packages.*, 
packages_parts.quantity") }
```

Now you can do `part.packages[0].quantity`, for example.

What this does is tell Rails to fetch the quantity key whenever it gets the packages for a specific part.

(You can do the same for your Package model if you want to do package.parts.first.quantity as well - just put this on the Package model also, replacing 'packages' with 'parts')

More info: https://ducktypelabs.com/using-scope-with-associations/