# Additional Foreign Key on a Join Table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a join table joining a Client and a Setor (plural: setores) models. The relation is that a Client has_and_belongs_to_many Setores (there are three Setores, a Client can have from one to all three of them. Setores have lots of Clients).

**My problem is:**
In this join table I added a reference to the User model. Setores have many Users, but a relation between one client and one setor have only one user. But I **don't know how to read and write this association on the clients_setores table**.

My models are as follows:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
has_and_belongs_to_many :documents
has_and_belongs_to_many :setores
has_many :screenings
has_many :contacts
has_many :interactions, through: :contacts
validates :cnpj, uniqueness: true


class Setor < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'setores'
  has_many :documents
  has_many :screenings
  has_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
  attr_acessor :user_id


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :setores
has_many :clients
```

And the current join tables parameters that have been working appear like this on the end of Clients controller:

```
  private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_client
  @client = Client.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def client_params
  params.require(:client).permit(:cnpj, :pacote, :razsoc, :vencimento, user_ids:[], document_ids:[], setor_ids:[])
end
```

Note that "user_ids:[]" was my attempt to get it to work, which has failed so far.

In the views I use the current join tables like this (taken from /client/_form.html.erb):

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :setor_ids, Setor.where(pacote: true), :id, :setor do |b| %>
```

So with these checkboxes I can create an entry in the clients_setores table.

**What I want to do** is to be able to pick a User that belongs to a given setor_id from a drop down menu and store this relation in the join table. I did manage to make such menu appear with the following code, in the same _form.html.erb:

```
<%= f.collection_select :user_ids, User.where(:setor_id => 1), :id, :email %>
```

But when I submit the form, the values are not saved. I don't know if my problem is just that I didn't get the right way to record this association on my view or if my problem is further down in the controller (probably) and model (maybe).

Closest problem I found in SO was [Rails 4 Accessing Join Table Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405624/rails-is-it-possible-to-add-extra-attribute-to-a-has-and-belongs-to-many-associ), but the association type is different (has_many/through) and there isn't a third relation involved, so I couldn't figure out how to make it work for me.

Comment: Hey I didn't fully understand your question so if you could clarify what you mean by "My problem is: In this join table I added a reference to the User model. "  The join table for a has_and_belongs_to_many only allows for two columns (the foreign keys to your setor and client table) so if you're saying you wanted to add a reference to that table you'll have to use a "has_many through" setup.  Also, you didn't put that your client belongs to a user in your Client model.

Comment: For a Client to have many Users, it would have to be through the same number of Setores (1 setor : 1 client; 3 setores: 3 clients), does the has_many/through relation work like this? As for the Client belonging to the User, it always belongs to as many Users as Setores; is this relevant?

Comment: Ok so you're saying if a client is to have one user, he must also have one setore?  Sorry I'm still not sure what you're trying to do but if you need a way to make sure that clients and setores also know about Users at the same time, you will need to use a "has_many through" association so that you can add additional columns to that join table to store the extra info on users.

Comment: Exactly. In the logical order of this system, a Client must first be assigned a Setor, only then it can have an User (from said Setor) assigned. (Setor means "department". If my client needs the service of, say, dept. of accounts payable, it gets a helper from this department)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of many-to-many associations between three models, done with a single join table:

I start out by generating some models:

```
rails g model User; rails g model Setor; rails g model Client;
rails g model Joiner user_id:integer setor_id:integer client_id:integer
```

By the way, `references` is a way to add a foreign key that refers to an existing model. I.e. `user:references` will create a user_id column. It also adds an "index" to the foreign key, which improves the performance.

Then I add some associations to the classes

```
class Joiner
  # columns: user_id, setor_id, client_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :setor
  belongs_to :client
end

class User
  has_many :joiners
  has_many :setors, through: :joiners, source: :setor
  has_many :clients, through: :joiners, source: :client
end

class Setor
  has_many :joiners
  has_many :users, through: :joiners, source: :user
  has_many :clients, through: :joiners, source: :client
end

class Client
  has_many :joiners
  has_many :users, through: :joiners, source: :user
  has_many :setors, through: :joiners, source: :setor
end
```

With this code written, you have many-to-many associations for the three models.

You can then write:

```
User.create; Setor.create;
Joiner.create(user_id: User.first.id, setor_id: Setor.first.id);
User.first.setors.length # => 1
```

This won't work for self-joins (i.e. a nested comment system), by the way, but that's not part of the question.

Comment: In this case, where would I store the relation between a Client and his (up to three) UserSetor pairings?

Comment: @SamOliver probably another join table. `ClientUserSetor` perhaps. It's not pretty, but it'll do the trick. By the way, look at the [detailed association reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: I read your first answer a few times and it gave me the idea of creating a new model, say "WeirdRelation", with a table that would store only the user_id, setor_id and user_id. This is not how I chose to solve this particular problem (see my answer below), but that's what I'd go with if I had more "Setores" per Client.

Comment: ok, that approach will work if you have a really simple case like this but im guessing the only reason you're doing that is because you don't really understand how to put together many-to-many relationships. Take a look at other stackoverflow questions on the topic.

Comment: @SamOliver I've re-done my answer to give you a more concrete example. Hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing to achieve the desired effect was to add three columns to the Client model:

userset1

userset2

userset3

This way a Client has up to three (since the field can be blank) relations with users, according to the Setores (departments) he has at his service.

This is the easiest solution **in this case** since I only have 3 Setores. It would not be for larger numbers.

If I had more than 3 Setores, making it impractical to keep adding columns in the Client table, I would cerate a new model just to store the relations, in this case, a table that would have, besides its unique ID, client_id, setor_id and user_id.